# Passing arguments to a thread in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I keep getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 37, in <module>
controller = threading.Thread(target=get_controller(), args=(q,))
TypeError: get_controller() missing 1 required positional argument: 'q'
```

Whenever I try to create a thread in python. Here's the code I'm using

```
def get_controller(q):
    q.put(get_gamepad())
return

q = queue.Queue()
events = []
controller = threading.Thread(target=get_controller(), args=(q,))
```

I know it's not the common error of forgetting to add a "," after the first argument in "args", but I'm not sure what else it could be.

Comment: You tried to call the function in `target=get_controller()`. Do `target=get_controller` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass the target, you should pass the pointer to the function you want. Instead, what you are doing is calling the function, which is not your desired effect. Try this instead:

```py
controller = threading.Thread(target=get_controller, args=(q,))
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `()` in `target=`

```py
threading.Thread(target=get_controller, args=(q,))
```